# Как работать с drawBitmapMesh?

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap

Саму ее я приблизительно разобрался как сделать

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image1);
float [] verst = {
          0,0 , 0,1 , 0,2 , 0,3 , 0,4,
          1,0 , 1,1 , 1,2 , 1,3 , 1,4,
          2,0 , 2,1 , 2,2 , 2,3 , 2,4,
          3,0 , 3,1 , 3,2 , 3,3 , 3,4 }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    canvas.drawBitmapMesh(this.bitmap ,int 3,int 3, verts , 0, null, 0, null);

}
```

А как работать с точкой? Двигать их по координатам, например, или вообще сохранить этот сдвиг в изображении.

Comment: В интернете популярное такое решение [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024860/android-image-warp-effect) но много чего не понятно,буду рад разьяснению даже того что есть

Comment: конкретно сам метод wrap,вообще непонятно что там происходит